# Ввод произвольного количества строк с клавиатуры

Tags: python

Как в Python ввести произвольное количество строк с клавиатуры?

Входные данные:

- 1 2 6
- 2 3 7
- 3 1 1
- 2 4 6
- ……………
- X Y W

Comment: Как должен определяться момент завершения ввода строк?

Comment: @andreymal, не всегда обязательно ждать завершения ввода чтобы сделать работу.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Решение зависит от того, что происходит с этими строками после ввода

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например:

```py
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == '':
        break
    # тут что-то делаем с inp
```

Ввод пустой строки - прекращение ввода.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте входной поток построчно:

```
import sys


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    # работа с введённой строкой
```